# Equivalent of createBarChart3D in JFreeChart 1.5.0?

Tags: java, jfreechart

JFreeChart 1.0.19 contained the method ChartFactory.createBarChart**3D**. That method is not available in JFreeChart 1.5.0.

Is there another 1.5.0 method that replaces createBarChart3D? Or is there a workaround (maybe including ChartFactory.createBarChart) to build a "3D" chart in 1.5.0? Or do I have to settle for "2D" charts after the upgrade?

JFreeChart 1.5.0's createBarChart does have a "3D-ish" look. Maybe it was decided that the improved createBarChart made createBarChart3D unnecessary?

Comment: Some options are suggested [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=119664).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod. Your link explains that the 3D charts are gone and replaced by improved 2D charts. So the options are to either stay on 1.0.19 and 3D charts, or upgrade to 1.5.0 and use 2D charts. I chose the the 2D charts in 1.5.0 (with their Mario-Brothers-pipe-3D-effect) since they in fact look better than the old 3D charts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. A noted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=119664) in 1.5.0, `createBarChart3D` is gone but `createBarChart` has been improved. So you either stay on 1.0.19 and use `createBarChart3D`, or upgrade to 1.5.0 and use `createBarChart` (or use another framework for your graphs).

1.5.0's `createBarChart` has a Mario-Brothers-pipe-3D-effect that (in my opinion) make it look better than 1.0.19's 3D charts. So my recommendation is to go for 1.5.0's `createBarChart`.

Comment: can you please post an example of creating a 3D Bar Chart using 1.5.0?

Comment: Replace createBarChart3D for createBarChart